# PyQt6 Error with giving Text from a LineEdit to a Label (Window closes itself)

Tags: python, pyqt6

I have a problem with PyQt6: i created a program with 2 windows. The error is at the second window, so you can ignore window 1. The problem is with a function, that takes the input of 4 lineEdits
and puts the 4 values to 4 labels to display them. I tried many things but nothing worked.

The Error: as soon i press the button to navigate to the next window, nothing opens and the error code `Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)` appears. When i try just to open window 2 the same error code appaers.

The function `giveDatatoÜbersicht` is the import function.
Code for window 2:

```py
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def giveDatatoÜbersicht(self):
        lineEdit3value = self.lineEdit_3.text()
        self.label_5 = lineEdit3value
        lineEdit4value = self.lineEdit_4.text()
        self.label_17 = lineEdit4value
        lineEdit13value = self.lineEdit_13.text()
        self.label_19 = lineEdit13value
        lineEdit14value = self.lineEdit_14.text()
        self.label_21 = lineEdit14value
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(804, 552)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(251, 255, 208);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setEnabled(True)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 801, 601))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setAccessibleName("")
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.tab_3)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 141, 31))
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("font-size: 30px;\n"
"text-decoration: underline;\n"
"font: 22pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.tab_3)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 120, 131, 21))
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("font: 12pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.label_16 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.tab_3)
        self.label_16.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 180, 191, 21))
        self.label_16.setStyleSheet("font: 12pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.label_16.setObjectName("label_16")
        self.label_18 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.tab_3)
        self.label_18.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 240, 61, 21))
        self.label_18.setStyleSheet("font: 12pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.label_18.setObjectName("label_18")
        self.label_20 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.tab_3)
        self.label_20.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 290, 61, 21))
        self.label_20.setStyleSheet("font: 12pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.label_20.setObjectName("label_20")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent=self.tab_3)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(610, 120, 171, 21))
        self.lineEdit_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 6px;\n"
"border: 1px solid black;")
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent=self.tab_3)
        self.lineEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(510, 180, 271, 21))
        self.lineEdit_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 6px;\n"
"border: 1px solid black;")
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.lineEdit_13 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent=self.tab_3)
        self.lineEdit_13.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(740, 240, 51, 21))
        self.lineEdit_13.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 6px;\n"
"border: 1px solid black;")
        self.lineEdit_13.setObjectName("lineEdit_13")
        self.lineEdit_14 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent=self.tab_3)
        self.lineEdit_14.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(740, 290, 51, 21))
        self.lineEdit_14.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 6px;\n"
"border: 1px solid black;")
        self.lineEdit_14.setObjectName("lineEdit_14")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.tab_3)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(720, 330, 71, 21))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 6px;\n"
"border: 1px solid black;")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.giveDatatoÜbersicht)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.tab_3)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 120, 191, 21))
        self.label_5.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 6px;\n"
"border: 1px solid black;\n"
"font: 12pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_5.setText("")
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_17 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.tab_3)
        self.label_17.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 180, 281, 21))
        self.label_17.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 6px;\n"
"border: 1px solid black;\n"
"font: 12pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_17.setText("")
        self.label_17.setObjectName("label_17")
        self.label_19 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.tab_3)
        self.label_19.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 240, 41, 21))
        self.label_19.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 6px;\n"
"border: 1px solid black;\n"
"font: 12pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_19.setText("")
        self.label_19.setObjectName("label_19")
        self.label_21 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.tab_3)
        self.label_21.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 290, 41, 21))
        self.label_21.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 6px;\n"
"border: 1px solid black;\n"
"font: 12pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_21.setText("")
        self.label_21.setObjectName("label_21")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.tab)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 81, 21))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent=self.tab)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 20, 113, 21))
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 6px;\n"
"border: 1px solid black;")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.tab)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 60, 81, 21))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent=self.tab)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 60, 191, 21))
        self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 6px;\n"
"border: 1px solid black;")
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.tab)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 110, 71, 31))
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.lineEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent=self.tab)
        self.lineEdit_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 110, 51, 31))
        self.lineEdit_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 6px;\n"
"border: 1px solid black;")
        self.lineEdit_5.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName("lineEdit_5")
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.tab)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 160, 71, 31))
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.lineEdit_7 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent=self.tab)
        self.lineEdit_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 160, 51, 31))
        self.lineEdit_7.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 6px;\n"
"border: 1px solid black;")
        self.lineEdit_7.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_7.setObjectName("lineEdit_7")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.tab)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 210, 71, 31))
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.lineEdit_6 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent=self.tab)
        self.lineEdit_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 210, 51, 31))
        self.lineEdit_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 6px;\n"
"border: 1px solid black;")
        self.lineEdit_6.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_6.setObjectName("lineEdit_6")
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.tab)
        self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 260, 71, 31))
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.lineEdit_8 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent=self.tab)
        self.lineEdit_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 260, 51, 31))
        self.lineEdit_8.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 6px;\n"
"border: 1px solid black;")
        self.lineEdit_8.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_8.setObjectName("lineEdit_8")
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.tab)
        self.label_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 20, 51, 31))
        self.label_10.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 6px;\n"
"border: 1px solid black;")
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.tab)
        self.label_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 60, 51, 31))
        self.label_11.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 6px;\n"
"border: 1px solid black;")
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.tab)
        self.label_12.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 60, 51, 31))
        self.label_12.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 6px;\n"
"border: 1px solid black;")
        self.label_12.setText("")
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        self.label_13 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.tab)
        self.label_13.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 20, 51, 31))
        self.label_13.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 6px;\n"
"border: 1px solid black;")
        self.label_13.setText("")
        self.label_13.setObjectName("label_13")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.tab)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 320, 131, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"font: 12pt \"Arial\";\n"
"border-radius: 8px;")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label_14 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.tab)
        self.label_14.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 20, 21, 31))
        self.label_14.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 6px;\n"
"border: 1px solid black;")
        self.label_14.setObjectName("label_14")
        self.label_15 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.tab)
        self.label_15.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 60, 21, 31))
        self.label_15.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 6px;\n"
"border: 1px solid black;")
        self.label_15.setObjectName("label_15")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(parent=self.tab_2)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 801, 591))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(5)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(1)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 4, item)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(130)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(50)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(70)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(49)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setSortIndicatorShown(False)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setStretchLastSection(False)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(parent=MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.tabWidget.setWhatsThis(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p>Übersicht</p><p><br/></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Übersicht:"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Titel des Projekts:"))
        self.label_16.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Beschreibung des Projekts:"))
        self.label_18.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "X-Wert:"))
        self.label_20.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Y-Wert:"))
        self.lineEdit_3.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Projektname eingeben"))
        self.lineEdit_4.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Projektbeschreibung eingeben"))
        self.lineEdit_13.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "  X-Wert"))
        self.lineEdit_14.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "  Y-Wert"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Bestätigen"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("MainWindow", "Übersicht"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Stück/Anzahl:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Bezeichnung:"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Obere Kante:"))
        self.lineEdit_5.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "X oder Y"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Rechte Kante:"))
        self.lineEdit_7.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "X oder Y"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Untere Kante:"))
        self.lineEdit_6.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "X oder Y"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Rechte Kante:"))
        self.lineEdit_8.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "X oder Y"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "X-Kante:"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Y-Kante:"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Spalte hinzufügen"))
        self.label_14.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "cm"))
        self.label_15.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "cm"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Spalte hinzufügen"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Test"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Stück/Anzahl"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Bezeichnung"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Breite"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Höhe"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Kantenbild"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.tableWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Tabelle"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I just tried to write the func "giveDatatoÜbersicht" a little bit shorter by writing:

```py
def giveDatatoÜbersicht(self):
    self.label_5 = self.lineEdit_3.text()
    self.label_17= self.lineEdit_4.text()
    self.label_19 = self.lineEdit_13.text()
    self.label_21= self.lineEdit_14.text()
```

Comment: Change the function name to `giveDatatoUbersicht` without the umlaut. Also: 1. `self.label_5 = self.lineEdit_3.text()` (like the following lines) is wrong: with that you're not setting the text of the label, you are *overwriting* the reference to the label with a *reference to the text*; if you want to set the text, then it should be `self.label_5.setText(self.lineEdit_3.text())`; 2. you should **not** edit pyuic files, it's a bad practice and also discouraged by the header you ignored and removed, instead read how to [use Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt6/designer.html)

Answer (score 0):

python can only read ascii characters, and Ü is not an ascii character. also, this doesnt apply to this case, since the python interpeter crashed, not pyqt6, but if you get 'Process finished with exit code -1' or any number that is not 0, then use a try exept statement to print the error.

Comment: Python 3 allows using non aschii characters for names, so that's not the actual problem, which instead **is** caused by PyQt, because the connection also uses byte conversion of the name for the signal, and it seems that PyQt doesn't allow that (but PySide does).

Comment: that's odd, i actually got an error saying 'python does not allow non ascii characters' when trying out your code (I'm using python 3.11)

Comment: That's not my code, I'm not the OP. And that error doesn't seem a Python error, it looks more like an IDE warning.